# Using Tone.js to add filters to an existing audio stream

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, tone.js

I was able to add filters to an existing audio stream using the biquadfilter but was interested in trying to use Tone.js instead. But I'm having issues connecting everything together. I keep getting a DomException when trying to connect the filter to an audioContext.

```
function addFilter(fq) {

    var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
    var mediaElem = document.getElementById('myAudioElement');

    //Tone.context = audioCtx;
    Tone.context.createMediaElementSource(mediaElem)

    const bqfilter = new Tone.Filter(fq, 'lowpass').toDestination();

    Tone.connect(bqfilter, audioCtx.destination);
    //bqfilter.chain(audioCtx.destination)
});
```

The error message is just DomException when I try to connect or chain the filter to the audioCtx.destination. This seems to follow most of the other examples I've found online so I'm not sure why this is throwing an exception.

*edit: included the stacktrace from the dev console

```
Uncaught DOMException                 Tone.js:formatted:2181 
connect     @ Tone.js:formatted:2181
To          @ Tone.js:formatted:8710
(anonymous) @ audiocontrols:983
dispatch    @ jquery.min.js:2
v.handle    @ jquery.min.js:2
```

Comment: I suggest you post the exact error message.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette The exact error message is just "Uncaught: DOMException" its really not informative at all.

It occurs when I try to do the `Tone.connect` or `bqfilter.chain`

Comment: Can't be just that... Normally, there at least is a line number where it is thrown and a stack trace.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I included the exact error message i'm getting from the console. Even if I was to look at the exact line where the error is occurring inside the Tone.js file its a minimized file and all its doing is throwing an exception when I try to run the connect

Comment: I admint I do not know tone.js... But definitely, the error cones from the /connect/ method. Here is the [documentation](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/14.7.77/Filter#connect). -- I am unsure about your second argument, which isn't a number. - Hoping my comment will help others help you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create your own `AudioContext`. You can just use the one from Tone.js. In fact that is even required. Otherwise your own `AudioNode` can't be connected to the one created by Tone.js.

The following should work:

```
function addFilter(fq) {
  const audioElement = document.getElementById('myAudioElement');
  const mediaElementSource = Tone.context.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
  const filter = new Tone.Filter(fq, 'lowpass').toDestination();

  Tone.connect(mediaElementSource, filter);
});
```

Please note that the `AudioContext` might be blocked by the browser's autoplay policy as described here: https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js#starting-audio.

Comment: I think this is really close. I'm now getting an error that says "Cannot connect from node with no outputs"

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. I had a typo in the example code. It should be fixed now.

Comment: I think this is working I just don't hear the filter effects. I tried adding start() but that doesn't seem to do anything. Is there a way to create a player so the effect can be heard? I'll mark this as accepted since it answers my original problem

Comment: Maybe your `fq` value is too high to hear any effect. Does it work if you set it very low? If you set it to 50 it should filter almost all audible sound.

Comment: I tried very high and very low but I still only hear the original audio from the `myAudioElement`. Do i need to create a Tone.player to get the audio played?

Comment: I'm seeing/hearing the same thing @Woodsy when I tried to use the code above. I tried it with a few other effects and got the same results. I'm curious as to why it isn't working.

Comment: Here's a CodeSandBox link of what I'm seeing if it helps: https://codesandbox.io/s/jsintrostarter-forked-ftucj4?file=/src/index.js  I can't hear the audio once it is connected to the filter.

Comment: Thanks for the test case. Somewhere in between all the console messages there was the following message: "MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions for https://ftucj4.csb.app/src/audio.mp3". For some reason CodeSandBox hosts the mp3 on a different domain. Adding `crossorigin="anonymous"` to the audio element should work. https://codesandbox.io/s/jsintrostarter-forked-bp80lf?file=/index.html